# How do you find the Lyapunov function for this ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes, stability-theory

This problem appears in In Perko section 2.9 problem 5b.

> Use the appropriate Liapunov function to determine the stability of the equilibrium points of the following system:
>   \begin{align}
> \frac{dx}{dt} &= x - 3y + x^3 \\
> \frac{dy}{dt} &= -x + y - y^2 \\
> \end{align}

My attempt at a solution for the equilibrium point $(x, y) = (0, 0)$:

If we linearize the system about the origin the we obtain a system with eigen values $\lambda = 1 \pm \sqrt{3}$, thus this is a hyperbolic unstable equilibrium point. So I would like $ \frac{dV(x(t), y(t))}{dt} > 0$ for my Liapunov function $V$.

Let $V(x, y) = ax^2 + by^2$ where $a, b > 0$.
Then $$\frac{dV}{dt} = 2ax^2 + 2by^2 + 2ax^4 - 2by^3 + (-6a - 2b)xy.$$
This is close to what I want but the $xy$ term is causing me trouble. I've also tried miscellaneous functions of the form $V(x, y) = x^{2m} + y^{2n}$ but similar issues arise. What other forms of Liapunov functions can I test? Is it possible that there is a typo in the text?

The convention for the Liapunov function is $V(0, 0) = 0$ and $V(x, y) > 0$ for $(x, y) \neq (0, 0)$.

Comment: It must be a mistake in the book. You can't show a *saddle point* to be unstable using a Liapunov function, since how could $\dot V>0$ hold on the *incoming* trajectories?

Comment: This makes sense, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the Chetaev's instability theorem:

$\bullet$ Let $x=0$ be an equilibrium point for the system
$$
\dot x=f(x),\quad x\in D\subseteq\mathbb R.
$$
Let $V:\,D\to \mathbb R$ be a continuously differentiable function such that $V(0)=0$ and $V(x_0)>0$ for some $x_0$ with arbitrarily small $\|x_0\|$.
Suppose that there exists a neighborhood $B_r$ of the origin such that 
$$
\forall x\in B_r\quad V(x)>0\;\Rightarrow\;\dot V ( x ) > 0.
$$
Then, $x=0$ is unstable. $\bullet$

Consider the function
$$
V(x,y)=-xy - y^2;
$$
$$
\dot V= -\dot x y-x\dot y-2y\dot y=-y(x - 3y + x^3)-x(-x + y - y^2)-2y(-x + y - y^2)
$$
$$
=3y^2-x^3y+x^2+xy^2-2y^2+2y^3=y^2-x^3y+x^2+xy^2+2y^3
$$
$$
=x^2(1-xy)+y^2(1-x+2y)
$$
From this point, it is obvious that the conditions of the theorem are
satisfied ($\dot V$ is positive not only for $\{(x,y)\in B_r:\;-xy - y^2>0\}$, but for all $(x,y)$ in some neighborhood $B_r$ of the origin).